# Join two recordsets with table() in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query two types with SQL.

The types are created as follows:

```
create or replace type MYCOLLSTRING is table of varchar2(4000)
```

Now I've got two PL/SQL collections of this type:

```
declare
    col1 MYCOLLSTRING;
    col2 MYCOLLSTRING;
begin
    col1 := MYCOLLSTRING();
    col2 := MYCOLLSTRING();
    col1.extend();
    col1(col1.last) := 'Test1';
    col1.extend();
    col1(col1.last) := 'Test2';
    col2.extend();
    col2(col2.last) := 'Test3';
    col2.extend();
    col2(col2.last) := 'Test4';
    --collections prepared

    select   *
    from     table(col1) x,
             table(col2) y;
    --here i'm trying to join x and y using their collection key
end;
```

As you can see in the query, I'm trying to join the two results by the recordset keys. As of now, the recordsets don't have a field name, so I neither now how to join on their values.

I'll appreciate your inputs!

Comment: What are you trying to join - can you show the result you expect? Four rows with one column, or two rows with two columns each? What is the 'key' - the index into the collection? Or the value in the collection element - where you don't currently have any matching `column_value`... (You need an `into` clause for a start, or a cursor).

Comment: @AlexPoole I'd like to have two rows finally, one Row `Test1 Test3` and the second row `Test2 Test4` so I'd like to join on the collection keys (`col1(1)` with `col2(1)` and `col1(2)` with `col2(2)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an index into the collection but you can only refer to it in a PL/SQL context.

```
for i in 1..col1.count loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i || ': ' || col1(i) || ', ' || col2(i));
end loop;
```

In your SQL query you could generate a pseudo-key based on the row number in each collection. You need to select into something, and if you want two columns you need a different collection type; for this example I've declared a record type and a table of that type:

```
declare
    type rec_type is record (c1 varchar2(4000), c2 varchar2(4000));
    type rec_table_type is table of rec_type;
    col1 MYCOLLSTRING;
    col2 MYCOLLSTRING;
    col3 rec_table_type;
begin
    ...
    select   x.column_value, y.column_value
    bulk collect into col3
    from     (select rownum as column_key, column_value from table(col1)) x
    join     (select rownum as column_key, column_value from table(col2)) y
    on       y.column_key = x.column_key;
    --here i'm trying to join x and y using their collection key    

    for i in 1..col3.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i || ': ' || col3(i).c1 || ', ' || col3(i).c2);
    end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1: Test1, Test3
2: Test2, Test4
```

Of course that assumes the base collections have the same number of elements; you can use outer joins to fix that if not. And depending on what you're doing, you may not actually need the third collection, and could just use a cursor to do the join and use that's results:

```
    for r in (
        select   x.column_value c1, y.column_value c2
        from     (select rownum as column_key, column_value from table(col1)) x
        join     (select rownum as column_key, column_value from table(col2)) y
        on       y.column_key = x.column_key
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.c1 || ', ' || r.c2);
    end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Test1, Test3
Test2, Test4
```

If you do want a third collection you could combine the two to populate it, without the SQL context switch:

```
    col3 := rec_table_type();
    for i in 1..col1.count loop
        col3.extend;
        col3(i).c1 := col1(i);
        col3(i).c2 := col2(i);
    end loop;

    for i in 1..col3.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i || ': ' || col3(i).c1 || ', ' || col3(i).c2);
    end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1: Test1, Test3
2: Test2, Test4
```

This still assumes the collections are the same size. If they aren't you can get subscript errors; you could either test the size before each element reference, or force them to be the same size by padding the smaller one with empty elements.

Comment: Genius! Thank you, this approach solves the problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

The default field is [COLUMN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns004.htm). Should be something like that:

```
select   *
from     table(col1) x,
         table(col2) y
where    x.COLUMN_VALUE = y.COLUMN_VALUE;
```

Comment: Isn't there another property like `COLUMN_KEY`? That's what I'm actually looking for...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The COLUMN_VALUE pseudocolumn represents the field header as in a real table, and therefore you should treat it like one.